# MVC View - Input selectors position is correct in Firefox but not in Chrome?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome

**Question background:**

I have an E-commerce site that has a  product detail page where users can select how many items of the item they wish to put in their basket.

**The Issue:**

When I look at the Product Detail view the left input selector is correctly positioned next to the input in Firefox but not in Chrome. The follow images show the issue and the differences between the two browsers:

***FireFox:***

The arrow green shows how the left selector is correctly positioned next to the input.
[image]

***Chrome:***

The  black arrow shows in Chrome the left selector is **not** positioned perfectly next to the input - note the increase in width:

[image]

**The code:**

The HTML for this input selector is simple, as shown:

```
<div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
    <input id="productQty" type="text" value="1" name="demo1" class="form-control">
</div>
```

**Any help with working out why this positioning in Chrome is wrong would be great.**

Comment: Use your browser tools to inspect the css for the elements

Comment: @StephenMuecke interestingly enough opening the developer console in Chrome caused a vertical scrolling bar on the right hand side of the page which was enough to push the input box over and make the gap between the selector and input box even like on FireFox. Am I missing something obvious here in the styling?

Comment: This question doesn't have anything to do with asp.net MVC. This is a CSS/bootstrap/browser question.

Comment: It's not in your html. It's in your css styling.

Comment: Try [Bootlinting](https://github.com/twbs/bootlint) your HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it IS positioned perfectly next to the input. They are pixel by pixel side by side. In Firefox one of them is overlapping the other by 1px.

Borders, paddings, and margins are treated slightly differently by different browsers. Often using the box-sizing css attribute can fix these things.

If you post the css related to those elements, a more specific solution could be given.

[MDN on box-sizing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)